# Trouble understanding dimensions of finite function spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

As stated, I have trouble understanding the dimensions of a finite function space and how to find a basis. I thought about what I understand and what I don't, but I feel like understanding nothing.

I know that a basis looks something like this, for some $g \in V$ where V is my function space,
$$g = a_1f_1 + a_2f_2 + ...$$
So, we find a bunch of $f_i$ that can in combination generate $g$. But for instance, let $V$ consist of functions only with finite elements ($f(\mathbb{R})$ is finite). How does one construct a basis for that and, therefore, know what dimensions $V$ has?

Comment: the functions with range in a finite set is not in general a vector space

Comment: @Exodd We're interested in the set of functions for which $f(\Bbb R)$ is finite, which is to say the space of [simple functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function). It is not stated that the codomain is finite.

Comment: @Max The space is infinite dimensional. There is indeed a basis for this set, but the cardinality of this basis (and therefore the dimension of the space) is the cardinality of the power set $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: For example, the functions $\chi_{[n,n+1]}$ are linearly independent, but they are infinitely many, meaning that any basis must have infinite cardinality